# Value becomes null mutable dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` and I'm trying to add values to that dictionary, I have a value is being sent from another page.

When I print the value outside the if block it prints but when I have an `NSLog` inside the if block the value is `null`.

I have tried like this:

```
self.qr1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.tablenu];
NSLog(@"qr code from scanner==%@",self.qr1);
self.title = @"Review Order";
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.custid =[defaults objectForKey:@"uid"];
self.phone=[defaults objectForKey:@"phnum"];
self.custname=[defaults objectForKey:@"custname"];
self.ordidsec=[defaults objectForKey:@"orderid"];
self.qrcodesec=[defaults objectForKey:@"qrcode"];

NSLog(@"defaults---%@ %@ %@ ",self.custname,self.custid,self.phone);
self.order_cart = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Order"] mutableCopy];

if (!_order_cart) {
    self.order_cart = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}


NSLog(@"qrrr %@",self.qr1);//this gives the value
if(_lname != NULL).        //This is the block.  
{

_tvar[@"item_name"] = _lname;
_tvar[@"item_quantity"] = _quan;
_tvar[@"price"] = _price;
_tvar[@"item_id"]=_idpro;
_tvar[@"phone"]=_phone;
_tvar[@"qr_code"]=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,self.qr1];
_tvar[@"_id"]=_id4;
_tvar[@"customer_name"]=_custname;
_tvar[@"customer_id"]=_custid;
    NSLog(@"qrrr indise %@",self.qr1);//this gives null

    NSLog(@"order caertttt=== %@",_tvar);
[_order_cart addObject:_tvar];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_order_cart forKey:@"Order"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSLog(@"qr 4555 added %@ --- %@",_cus33tname,[_tvar valueForKey:@"dd"]);
    NSLog(@"qr added %@ --- %@",_qr1,[_tvar valueForKey:@"qr_code"]);

}
```

Aim:- I want to add the value in that dictionary

Def :-

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *qr1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *tvar;
```

Comment: How is defined `qr1` in your class?

Comment: property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *qr1; @Larme

Comment: And when you do `NSLog(@"qr added %@ --- %@"`_qr1,...` is it null there? I'm wondering if you have a custom setter or getter on `qr1`. Or maybe implement one, to check when its value is replaced.

Comment: outside this block it gives the value but inside it is giving (null) @Larme

Comment: where is the block in your question

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik check the question I have edited now

Comment: is the condition not a block

Comment: https://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/If_()_Then,_Else_(block) a line of codes can be called a block generally then how do u call code inside if condition I would call it as a if block hence block @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: and the question is not abt that, its abt the solution or suggestions @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: In objective-C a block typically refers to an anonymous function that is often passed to an asynchronous operation to be invoked on completion.  Typically what you are describing as a block would be just "inside the `if` statement".  Are you sure that `self.qr1` and `_lname` both have values *at the same time*?  Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code to see what is happening?

Comment: @Paulw11 ya I have values

Comment: @Paulw11 at NSLog out side "if" is giving me the qr code result

Comment: All I can say is set a breakpoint and use the debugger.  What you think is happening and what is happening are different things.